# Xcode UITest, checking existence with timeout

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I'm trying to check, in Xcode's UITests, the existence of a button that is present in my login view.

I tried (and used, in other parts of the code) the `expectationForPredicate` method with the `waitForExpectationsWithTimeout` method, but when the button is not visible, it'll fail the test.

So my attempt is:

```
func isLoggedIn(timeout: UInt32 = 10) -> Bool{
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    let msToWait : UInt32 = 100

    for _ in 1 ... (timeout * 1000 / msToWait) {
        if(app.buttons["Sign in with email"].exists){
            return false;
        }
        usleep(msToWait * 1000)
    }
    return true;
}
```

and `app.buttons["Sign in with email"].exists` doesn't work, it always returns false.

Tried different values of msToWait and `sleep(1)` instead of `usleep()`, same result.

And, of course, the button exists (`app.buttons["Sign in with email"].tap()` works).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to let the run loop run, try sleeping with:

```
RunLoop.current.run(until:Date(timeIntervalSinceNow:0.001))
```